# What is the easiest way to move a function within a wxPython class to a different thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I am relatively new to Python but am using it to hack together some automation. I am having a bit of trouble with Classes and how functions within speak to functions outside. My real goal is to create a thread out of an existing function without requiring a rewrite of most of my code.

Here is my current model. I have a super class `AppWindow(wx.Frame)` and within it there are many functions defined.

`InitUI` creates the interface and initializes variables.
`ProcessComputers` reaches out to different workstations to gather some info. This relies heavily on a module I had written when this application was console-based.
There are various other misc. functions that aren't really worth calling out.

This obviously is bad for the GUI since everything is dependent on those processes completing before the screen can refresh and accept events.

Since `ProcessComputer` is already separate from my UI functions, I am wondering what is the easiest way to move these functions into a separate thread, without having to rewrite and rename objects and variables?

I have tried creating a new class as suggested [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui). The problem is when I created the two new classes, and move the guts of `ProcessComputer` to the CountEvent class, everything broke. I could no longer update a self.textField from `AppWindow` nor could I refer to it using AppWindow.textField. None of my variables were accessible to the new class. Is there a better way of moving this function into its own class, without rewriting too much of the code that is currently working?

If not, what is the best way of rewriting the guts of `ProcessComputer` so they still play with the rest of the code within `AppWindow`?

Comment: You cannot directly access GUI elements from other threads anyway. There are ways but it is better to try to fully separate the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the ProcessComputer function where it's at and have your GUI call it. But put its guts into a function in a class that's based on Thread. Then when you need to update the GUI, you'll have to call one of wxPython's thread-safe methods: wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater or wx.PostEvent.

Here are a couple of good resources:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

This is kind of what your thread class will look like:

```
 ########################################################################
class TestThread(Thread):
    """Test Worker Thread Class."""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, wxObject):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.wxObject = wxObject
        self.start()    # start the thread

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self):
        """Run Worker Thread."""
        # This is the code executing in the new thread.
        for i in range(6):
            time.sleep(10)
            amtOfTime = (i + 1) * 10
            wx.PostEvent(self.wxObject, ResultEvent(amtOfTime))
        time.sleep(5)
        wx.PostEvent(self.wxObject, ResultEvent("Thread finished!"))
```

The rest of the code can be similar to the example in the 2nd link. Or you can use the first link to the wiki to see a couple of other approaches.

Comment: Thanks! Just for some clarification, my `ProcessComputer` function does two things: it does some work against the computers, but it also logs the results of these to a text control in the UI. Will moving it to a function in a class based on thread prevent me from writing to the text fields?

Comment: Also [`wx.lib.delayedresult`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.delayedresult-module.html) is a great convenience library usable for most of the multi-threading tasks.

Comment: No, you can just redirect stdout to a text control. Check out my answer to a similar question earlier this week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471007/redirect-command-prompt-output-to-a-python-generated-window/15479602#15479602