# Printing Scapy output to wxPython Text Controller

Tags: python, wxpython, scapy

Thank you for taking time to look at my question.

I am learning the ropes of wxPython and I want to take a working program that outputs to terminal and give it a face lift. With Scapy, I am sniffing my wireless interface for Probe Requests/Probe Responses and it works as intended. I want to however, instead of outputting to the Terminal window, output it to a StaticText (tc2) frame within my new GUI.

Now I have been using a tutorial to create my GUI thus far however, the current code still outputs Scapy to terminal before even loading my GUI since the sniff function runs until its killed by the user thus never really loading the GUI. I have tried placing the sniff function within the wx.StaticText line but no joy on getting it to print there.

Both my Scapy program and GUI program work on their own however they don't work simultaneously together. My goal is to have the return values displayed to the StaticText box. Below is a small portion of my code relevant to my question.

```
tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,100), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)

btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Sniff', size=(70, 30))
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSniff, btn1)

redir=RedirectText(tc2)
sys.stdout=redir

def OnSniff(self,e):
sniff(iface="mon0",prn=packets,store=0)

def packets(p):
if p.haslayer(Dot11ProbeReq):
    dstmac=p.addr1
    mac=p.addr2
    if p.info == "":
    ssid="BROADCAST"
    else:
    ssid=p.info

    print "%s is probing %s %s" % (mac,dstmac,ssid)

if p.haslayer(Dot11ProbeResp):
    dstmac=p.addr1
    bssid=p.addr2
        ssid=p.info
        print "%s (%s) Probe Response to %s" % (ssid,bssid,dstmac)

wx.Yield()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to start your sniffing until the wxPython app had loaded. So you'll either want to start the sniffing in a button or menu event handler or you could use wx.CallLater to start the execution AFTER the app has loaded by putting the CallLater command at the end of your wx code's init.

I did something kind of like this when I redirected a ping command (among other things). You can take a look at my [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/05/python-running-ping-traceroute-and-more/) on the subject. If you need more background on redirecting stdout, see [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/01/01/wxpython-redirecting-stdout-stderr/).

The basic gist of the matter was covered in another of my answers here: [Redirect command prompt output to a python generated window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471007/redirect-command-prompt-output-to-a-python-generated-window/15479602#15479602)

Basically you want to redirect the text using something like this:

```
class RedirectText:
    def __init__(self,aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self,string):
        self.out.WriteText(string)
```

And then in my ping example, I did the following:

```
def pingIP(self, ip):
    proc = subprocess.Popen("ping %s" % ip, shell=True, 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    print
    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()                        
        wx.Yield()
        if line.strip() == "":
            pass
        else:
            print line.strip()
        if not line: break
    proc.wait()
```

The main thing to look at is the stdout parameter in your subprocess call and the wx.Yield() is important too. The Yield allows the text to get "printed" (i.e. redirected) to stdout. Without it, the text won't show up until the command is finished. I hope that all made sense.

In case you need to run this in a separate thread, here are a couple links on that subject:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Comment: Mike, you have got me going on the right track. I got it to display one line but now I am running into a problem with it freezing. I press Sniff, and it freezes. I am guessing its getting hung up somewhere in the text redirection. I have used your resources to guide me. Here is what I have done.

Comment: I don't see wx.Yield anywhere in your code. It's possible that you'll need to do the Sniff code inside a thread and use wx.CallAfter to post it back to the GUI. I'm not familiar with this sniffer though. You might think about cross-posting to the wxPython mailing list. They're very helpful there!

Comment: I see what you are getting at and since the sniff continues to run until closed by the user it will never redirect. Let me look more up on threading and I will come back to this and let you know how it went. Thanks Mike!

Comment: Got it to work Mike! Thank you so much, I just had to add wx.Yield() to end of my packets function and it worked.

Comment: Cool. I figured you needed the Yield somewhere